# TypeScript gives 'Object is possibly undefined' error after importing object in React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to TypeScript and I'm getting 'Object is possibly undefined' errors after importing an object and attempting to iterate over the arrays inside the object.

I attempted to use the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) to no effect.

[Here is a code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/imported-object-wo3jn?file=/src/ComponentWithoutProps.tsx). I'm not particularly happy with the conditional rendering solution found in App with *ComponentWithProps*. Is that the best way to do this?

Any and all feedback would be great!
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object that is possible undefined is not `calendar`, but it's the result of the find function call, which is either the type of an array element, or undefined as can be seen in typescript 4.3.5 declarations:

```
find<T>(value: T, ...): T | undefined;
```

you need to assert that it's not undefined before accessing the `name` property:

```
let time = calendar.hours.find((thisHour) => thisHour.number === 2);

if (time !== undefined) {
    time = time.name;
}
```

or, a more elegant solution, using the `||` (logical OR) [short circuit evaluation](https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-is-short-circuit-evaluation-ff22b2f5608c) provided with a fallback default value:

```
let time = calendar.hours.find((thisHour) => thisHour.number === 2)?.name || 'fallbackName';
```

if your fallback is `undefined` (just like my first solution) then you can just use the `?` [optional chaining syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) without the rest of the line:

```
let time = calendar.hours.find((thisHour) => thisHour.number === 2)?.name;
```